# Run some code when a popup closes in my swing app

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

In my app I display a popup using `JPopupMenu`. I want to run some code when this popup closes (either directly, programmatically or when escape key is pressed). For windows I can attach a `WindowListener` but `JPopupMenu` doesn't have any corresponding feature, and `SwingUtilities.windowForComponent` returns the root window of the app. How do I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

How about adding a `PopupMenuListener` to it? Something like:

```
jpopMenu.addPopupMenuListener(new PopupMenuListener 
{
  public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent popupMenuEvent) 
  {
    //here the code you want to be executed at close
  }
  public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent popupMenuEvent){}
  public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent popupMenuEvent) {}
}
```

This should be automatically executed when you *cancel/close* the `popMenu`. I didn't add code to the other two methods, but feel free to play with them if needed.